# Ist „Rechner“ oder „Computer“ korrekt?

Tags: synonym

<sub>German / Deutsch</sub>
Ich schreibe aktuell eine Facharbeit und habe bisher immer den Begriff „Computer“ benutzt.

Nun meinte jemand zu mir, ob nicht vielleicht „Rechner“ der korrekte Begriff wäre. Ich weiß es nicht genau, irgendwie war ich bisher immer der Meinung, dass „Rechner“ eher umgangssprachlich sei.

---

<sub>English / Englisch</sub>
I’m currently writing my so called “skilled work” and I’m not quite sure if I should use “Computer” or “Rechner”. The full work is currently written with “Computer” but some guy told me that I should use “Rechner” instead. I don’t see a reason why but maybe you guys can help me.

Comment: Es ist eine Facharbeit im Leistungskurs Informatik über "Rootkits"

Comment: Just be sure to *not* use "Elektronengehirn"

Comment: Vielleicht interessant... fh Flensburg empfielt "computer" da "Rechner" auch ein Mensch sein kann.  http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/diplarbtips.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Note: Because you took the liberty of asking your question in English, too, and because it might be found by people whose German is not too good, I’m going to provide an English answer.*

The words *Computer* and *Rechner* are full synonyms of each other when used to describe the big machine that works with electricity. Unfortunately, that doesn’t work for all of their compounds: *Taschenrechner, Großrechner* but *Computernutzer*. The ones with the other word are possible but anything from ‘sound weird’ to ‘mean something different’. However, there are rare cases, where even the compound can be formed with both: *rechnerunterstützt* and *computerunterstützt*.

While the etymology of *Rechner* is not hard (something that does calculations for you), Germans usually wouldn’t know that *Computer* also derives from Latin *computare* and the English word was used throughout the ages for a [profession](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29470/etymology-of-computer-before-computer-referred-to-a-machine) known as *Rechner* in German. They didn’t mix because there was no need for anglicisms then.

While the two words are interchangeable, there can be reasons to use one or the other preferably. For one, many people dislike anglicisms and would prefer to use *Rechner* all the time. Similarly, when writing an essay in German class, *Rechner* might just fit in nicer with the surroundings. On the other hand in computer sciences (the area in which the OP said in comments his work is going to be handed in to), *Computer* might be preferred because it is almost like a technical term.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the compounds... a clear sign that both words are equally standard

Comment: Ein Random-Downvote ohne Kommentar ein Jahr nach der Antwort?

Answer (score 16):

*Computer* und *Rechner* sind im Deutschen völlig synonym zueinander. Weder Rechner noch Computer ist umgangssprachlich.

Ich würde in der Facharbeit Computer benutzen, weil es ein Fachwort ist und es meines Erachtens heute im Zusammenhang mit *elektronischen Rechenanlagen* häufiger benutzt wird.

(Eine gute, ausführlichere Erweiterung dieser Antwort bietet die [Antwort von Jan](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23748/15920).)

Answer (score 5):

Lateinisch **computare** = deutsch **berechnen**.

Vor jener Zeit, als Maschinen zum Rechnen eingesetzt wurde, gab es einen Beruf, den Menschen ausgeübt haben, und der im englischen Sprachraum »Computer« genannt wurde. Computer waren Menschen, die z.B. in der Astronomie, aber auch in anderen wissenschaftlichen Disziplinen, mit Papier und Bleistift, für höherrangige Wissenschaftler langwierige Berechnungen durchgeführt haben.

Als dann im zwanzigsten Jahrhundert Maschinen diese Arbeit schneller und fehlerfreier durchführen konnten, bezeichnete man auch diese Maschinen als Computer.

Computer sind also nichts anderes als Rechner. Computer berechnen etwas. Und das tun sie heute noch immer.

Comment: +1 Wieder was gelernt. Und beim Nachrecherchieren noch einen Thread auf einer Schwester-Site gefunden: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29470/etymology-of-computer-before-computer-referred-to-a-machine

Answer (score 4):

*Rechner* ist einfach das deutsche Wort für *Computer* und beide werden üblicherweise im Deutschen synonym benutzt. Falsch ist in dem genannten Kontext also keins der beiden Wörter.

Allerdings gibt es viele Personen, die entweder eine Abneigung gegen Anglizismen oder gegen die Eindeutschung internationaler Alltagsbegriffe haben, oder die das Gefühl haben, dass die Verwendung des Begriffs, der ihnen subjektiv als weniger alltäglich und umgangssprachlich erscheint, sachlicher, wertiger oder "richtiger" ist.

Sollte der Prüfer einen Begriff stark bevorzugen, empfiehlt es sich, sich einfach danach zu richten. Ansonsten kann man sich auch immer nach dem Wortgebrauch in den verwendeten Quellen richten - sollte die "falsche" Begriffsverwendung dann zu Schwierigkeiten führen, kann man sich immer auf die Autorität der Vorlage berufen.

Comment: Es mag vielleicht Sprachpuristen geben, die eine gewisse Ablehnung gegenüber Anglizismen haben, jedoch sind diese Begriffe insbesondere in der IT weit verbreitet und ich würde sie sogar schon als Lingua Franca für alle Sprachen ansehen.

Comment: @user3147268: "Lingua Franca für alle Sprachen" - das ist aber etwas weit gegriffen. In Frankreich und Spanien ist das Wort "Computer" im Vergleich zu "ordinateur" und "ordenador" schon mal eher gar nicht verbreitet, im spanischsprachigen Lateinamerika ist es zwar das klanglich ähnlichere "computadora", aber auch nicht "Computer".

Comment: Danke für denn Hinweis. Dann kann man in **vielen** Sprachen durch diese Begriffe den Kontext erschließen.

Comment: Ein Prüfer hat persönliche Vorlieben hinten anzustellen und darf diese nicht in die Bewertung einfließen lassen. Das wäre unprofessionell. Aufgabe des Studenten ist es nicht unprofessionelles Verhalten zu unterstützen.

Answer (score 1):

Computer und Rechner sind als Wörter austauschbar. Die Wahl des Begriffes sollte sich nach dem Leserkreis richten.

Ich würde aber bei der Wahl berücksichtigen, in welcher Sprache die weiteren Begriffe genannt werden. Wenn es um Stapel und Halden (-speicher) geht, um Programmmanipulation usw. ist "Rechner" sicher in Ordnung. Wenn aber Stack, Heap und Code Injection<sup>1</sup> wichtiger Bestandteil ist, ist "Computer" besser geeignet. Die Grenze zwischen der Verwendung fremdsprachlicher Fachbegriffe und Denglisch ist fließend.

<sup>1 Das gilt nur als Beispiel und kann beliebig erweitert warden.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde einfach variieren, also mal Rechner und mal Computer schreiben.

Je nach Verwendungszweck ist vielleicht auch "Server" oder "Arbeitsplatzrechner" ganz gut. Bei "Server" muss man allerdings unterscheiden zwischen der Server-Hardware und z.B. der Application Server Software.

Gelegentlich schreibe ich selbst auch z.B. "Datenbank-Maschine" (ja, ich weiß, man sollte das ohne Bindestrich schreiben, aber ich finde so liest es sich angenehmer).

Comment: Mir wurde bereits gesagt, dass die beiden Begriffe vollkommen Synonym zueinander sind und dass man sich in einer Wissenschaftlichen Arbeit auf einen Begriff beschränken soll